# i got the issue when i am running my UI

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a error what i got when i was running my UI... please help me to fix this issue

```
C:\Users\nuwan_rates\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 

java.io.IOException: Cannot create destination folder: G:\Theory\Back up\SmartNurseApplication\build\classes
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.usages.BuildArtifactMapperImpl.ensureBuilt(BuildArtifactMapperImpl.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.translateEntry(TranslateClassPath.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.translate(TranslateClassPath.java:107)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath.execute(TranslateClassPath.java:96)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Does the path exist?

Comment: \......build\classes ya this path is exist but empty folder (Classes)